# How can I create folders in my Start > All Programs menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Adobe creates tons of application icons in my Start > All Programs menu.

I want to drop them all in their own folder. How can I do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 8):

- Right click on All Programs
- Select Open
- Double-Click Programs
- Click New Folder in Toolstrip
- Name the folder
- Press Enter
- Move shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and create the desired folders.

Edit: So, I'm guessing that the path that I posted has replaced what was C:\Documents and Settings\All Users in XP.  The [path Diago describes](https://superuser.com/questions/28415/how-can-i-create-folders-in-my-start-all-programs-in-win7/28419#28419), C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu, is what used to be C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu.